# Previous & Next buttons on a loop for custom WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress, loops, menu

So I've got to loop some pages with previous and next buttons...

Basically you have the first page which lists a bunch of pages in that category then when you click on of the links it takes you to a "detail" page and on that is where I need the buttons.

Just want a simple way of doing this rather then putting in link manually on each "detail" page...

Any suggestions?

Much appreciated.

Terry

Answer (score 0):

Did you need same as you see in post section of wp?

category page with list of post with their excerpt and when you click on it you go to that post where you can navigate to prev or next post?

Comment: This is what I needed http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-show-links-to-previousnext-page-by-menu_order but I want it to just loop round the child pages under that parent.